# Push a local branch to a new project on remote

Tags: git, github, git-branch

This may be a little atypical. I am working on a local branch of an *existing* personal project, and I haven't push it to the remote (GitHub) yet.

As my local branch evolves, I now decide to create a *new* project altogether based on this branch, and I would like to push all the code in this branch to the master of the new project.

Lastly, I don't want to modify anything on the remote for the existing/old project. How should I do it using git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have created a new project on github, get the url of the repo and do:

```
git push <new_project_url> <local_branch>:master
```

Comment: what would happen to the local branch of the old project? Will git automatically change it to the master belonging to the new project?

Comment: @skyork - The projects are independent, as they should be. What you do for the one, doesn't affect the other.

Answer (score 2):

### Add a new remote and push to it

Assuming the new project exists, from the existing working copy add a new remote for the new project:

```
-> git remote add new-remote git@github.com/me/new-project.git
```

And then push to it:

```
-> git checkout new-branch # If not already on "the new" branch
-> git push
fatal: The current branch new has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin new-branch
-> git push --set-upstream new-remote master
```

Note that the error message given when you attempt to push on a branch that isn't tracking anything gives the command necessary to setup a tracking branch.

This will modify the `.git/config` file like  so:

```
[remote "new-remote"]
    url = git@github.com/me/new-project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/new-remote/*
[branch "new-branch"]
    remote = new-remote
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Giving the option to push/pull from that branch in the future.